# Why is this sudo command try to run in /root?

Tags: bash, ssh, shell, sudo

I try to run a sudo command via SSH like this:

```
ssh domain.com sudo -u user bash -c "cd /home/user/ && ls"
```

(which is obiously just an example).

I get back:

```
/home/user/: line 0: cd: /root: Permission denied
```

I wonder why sudo tries to change into /root?

Comment: Is your `cd` function aliased to something custom?

Comment: It's hard to tell without know what's an example and what's the real thing. What's the user's home directory?

Comment: If it was me I would probably try passing a `-v` option to ssh to make sure that is doing what you expect, then I might use preface your remote command with strace.  You will get lots of verbose detail that way, but it might send you the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that there are two ways of approaching this:

1. Focusing on getting your command to run in the correct directory.  For that, I would suggest the `-i` flag to sudo, which will set things up to be an environment as though you'd logged in as that user, so:

   ```
   ssh domain.com sudo -iu user ls
   ```
2. Focus on solving the quoting issue, so that your quoted command can still be treated as one argument to `bash`, so that it will be executed as a single command-string.  For that, in this case, it seems you just need one more level of quoting, like so:

   ```
   ssh domain.com sudo -u user bash -c "'cd /home/user/ && ls'"
   ```

   or:

   ```
   ssh domain.com sudo -u user bash -c '"cd /home/user/ && ls"'
   ```

   Explanation: The shell where you invoke ssh takes up one set of quotes, passing ssh the following (using the first example above) list of arguments (as `argv`, after `argv[0]` of ssh):

   1. `domain.com`
   2. `sudo`
   3. `-u`
   4. `user`
   5. `bash`
   6. `-c`
   7. `'cd /home/user && ls'`

   This then causes sudo to get an arguments list of:

   1. `-u`
   2. `user`
   3. `bash`
   4. `-c`
   5. `cd /home/user && ls`

   which sudo then parses its own arguments out of, and then hands the rest to bash otherwise unmodified, such that bash receives the arguments:

   1. `-c`
   2. `cd /home/user && ls`

   and bash then takes its second argument as a command string, as though it had been typed in to an interactive shell, and it then runs the first command (`cd /home/user`), also (because of `&&`) running the second (`ls`) if the first succeeds.

Frankly, I'd probably go with the first option... But the second also works for your trivial example, and depending on the reality of your real problem, may or may not be a better fit for you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, @Zoredache's advise was the one that helped the most here:

when you issue

```
ssh domain.com sudo -u user bash -c "cd /home/user/ && ls"
```

from the source host, on the destination host this is actually run

```
sudo -u user bash -c cd /home/user/ && ls
```

which translates into

```
sudo -u user bash -c cd /root
```

as a cd without an argument changes into the home directory and this is in this case not the home directory of the sudo user but the home directory of the user who issues sudo (ie root)

the solution is to escape every single special character like this

```
sudo -u user bash -c \"cd /home/ \&\& ls\"
```

but I'm sure there is an easier way, or is it?

Comment: Your explanation is correct, but I think the solution can be simpler: just put single quotes around the whole `sudo ...` command.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permission to view the `/` directory?

If not then try this:

```
ssh domain.com sudo -u user bash -c "cd ~ && ls"
```

If you do then try running this:

```
ssh domain.com sudo -u user bash -c "cd /home/user/ && ls && whoami && groups user"
```